# Unity crashes during build

Tags: unity-game-engine

Whenever I try to start the build process, I select the path, and Unity immediately freezes. There is no warning or error. Eventually it just silently closes the editor completely, and nothing has been exported.
I tried using an empty scene as the only scene selected for export, that too has failed.
I am running on a 2017 Macbook pro, i7, 16Gb DDR
Has anyone encountered this behaviour?

Comment: There's really not much to diagnose here as your issue could be anything (your computer specs are fine, btw).  Since this isn't specifically programming related, I'll point you to the [GameDev StackExchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) to ask there.  Either way, here are some things you can try: 1) Look for the [editor logs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) for clues. 2) Make sure you don't have build scripts with infinite loops. 3) Close Unity, delete the "Library" directory along with all its contents, and re-open Unity and try again... or 4) Reinstall Unity.

Comment: Thank you so much! After some digging around in the editor logs I found that one of the 3rd party assets had some code messing up the build pipe line.

Comment: Glad it worked! I honestly thought this question would be closed since there isn't a ton of detail but that doesn't seem to be the case so I turned my comment into an answer so this question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really not much to diagnose here as your issue could be anything (your computer specs are fine, btw). Since this isn't specifically programming related, I'll point you to the [GameDev StackExchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) to ask there. Either way, here are some things you can try:

1. Look for the [editor logs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) for clues.
2. Make sure you don't have build scripts with infinite loops.
3. Close Unity, delete the "Library" directory along with all its contents, and re-open Unity and try again or...
4. Reinstall Unity.